# parse snort log file( .txt file to .xml file fomat)

Tags: xml, parsing, snort

I want to parse snort log file to get data into xml format.
I am looking for most efficient way(in terms of speed) for this conversion. I don't want to use any tool for it, I am planning to write a code, or will reuse if any code already available. Can you please suggest me how to achieve this efficiently?
My friend said that I need to parse log file using python and then convert it into xml. Please suggest me your opinion.

Just want conversion should be speed efficient(from log file to xml file)

Thanks :-)

Comment: Choose whatever language you want. Differences are marginal and mostly depend on how the implementation is done. For max performance be a assembler ninja :D

Comment: Thanks for input, is log file-> python->xml is possible? if yes then can you suggest me some sample code?  
If anyone know any better way then plz do share your thoughts.

Comment: Of course it's possible. Read python docs/tutorials about simple file processing and xml and you're done.